# SSMS Collation conflict when expand Tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, ssms

some strange SSMS behaviour annoyed me for the last few days.
I'm using EF Core 5 Code First and trying to create a test database with `EnsureCreated()`. The code runs fine and database appears on my local server. But when I try to expand Tables in SSMS I get following error:

[image]

I'm using mssql docker container which is configured for German language (`MSSQL_LCID: 1031`).

Also, we have production database dumps that I can restore on my local machine and get everything work fine.

Here are default server and database collation which I found in properties:

- server: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`
- database from dump: `Latin1_General_CI_AS`
- database from `EnsureCreated()`: `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

So as you see collations for each databases are the same. But I don't get conflict on restored one!

**UPDATE:**

Here are some details of error (retrieved by clicking Show details button)

```
===================================

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

------------------------------
For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.NavigableItemBuilderDataReader.RunQuery()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.NavigableItemBuilderDataReader.Process()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.NavigableItemBuilderDataReader.get_PropertyNames()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.BuildDynamicItemWithQuery(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, String urnQuery, Boolean registerBuilder, Boolean registerBuiltItems)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.BuildDynamicItem(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, IFilterProvider filter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.Build(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, IFilterProvider filter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NonContextFilterNavigableItemBuilder.Build(IList`1 targetList, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, IFilterProvider filter)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItem.RequestChildren(IGetChildrenRequest request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ExplorerHierarchyNode.BuildChildren(WaitHandle quitEvent)

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteReader(String sqlCommand, SqlCommand& command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataReader(String query, SqlCommand& command)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DataProvider.SetConnectionAndQuery(ExecuteSql execSql, String query)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecuteSql.GetDataProvider(StringCollection query, Object con, StatementBuilder sb, RetriveMode rm)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillData(ResultType resultType, StringCollection sql, Object connectionInfo, StatementBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.FillDataWithUseFailure(SqlEnumResult sqlresult, ResultType resultType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.BuildResult(EnumResult result)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlObjectBase.GetData(EnumResult erParent)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Environment.GetData(Request req, Object ci)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.GetData(Object connectionInfo, Request request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.Enumerator.Process(Object connectionInfo, Request request)

===================================

Ein Sortierungskonflikt zwischen "Latin1_General_CI_AS" und "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" im UNION ALL-Operator, der in der 2-Spalte der SELECT-Anweisung auftritt, kann nicht aufgelöst werden.
Die Sicht oder Funktion "sys.all_columns" konnte aufgrund von Bindungsfehlern nicht verwendet werden. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=14.00.3411&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=451&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: localhost
Error Number: 451
Severity: 16
State: 1
Procedure: all_columns
Line Number: 2


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.GetExecuteReader(SqlCommand command)
```

Seems like it comes from view all_columns. I also can't do any select from this system view nor event see its columns.

Comment: The only time I've seen errors like that is when someone has tried to change the database's/server's collation after it was created, and it went.... "wonky".

Comment: Maybe... but I tried to make a clean experiment and did drop and re-create of docker container and then tried to create the database.
Also it worked before for me. Then it crashes week ago but started to work on next day. And now it doesn't work again

Comment: Are you using the most up-to-date version of SSMS?

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm using `15.0.18369.0` which is pretty up to date (latest is `15.0.18390.0`)

Comment: I'd use Extended Events or Profiler to capture the actual query that SSMS sends that encounters the error and then see what objects specifically have incompatible collations and if anything can be done about it, or report it as a bug if it is a bug in the query not handling legitimately different collations correctly

Comment: I added more details. Please check it. Thanks.

Comment: `sys.all_columns` definition is just `SELECT * FROM sys.columns UNION ALL SELECT * FROM sys.system_columns` so that explains why `UNION ALL` is also mentioned. Not really an SSMS issue then if `sys.all_columns` is itself broken. So you need to research how `sys.columns` and `sys.system_columns` have ended up with different collations

Comment: If you have only just started getting this issue have you done anything to the collation of your `model` database?

Comment: No, I just did what I do every day - recreate database for work, integration tests etc. Nothing with collations (actually I didn't know anything about collations in Sql server before)